# Javascript implement array stack without using existing methods

Tags: javascript, stack

I am very new to javascript have experince in java to implement stack but i want learn how we can do it using javascript

Have to implement following method without using existing one

1. Push
2. Pop
3. Concat
4. Reduce

I have tried

```js
class Stack {
  constructor() {
    this._last = null;
    this._length = 0;
  }
  pop() {
    const top = this._last;
    if(this._length>0 && top) {
      this._last = top._last;
      this._length--;
      return top.data;
    }
    return null;
  }
  push(data) {
    const item = new Item(data, this._last);
    this._last = item;
    this._length++;
  }
  
  get length() {
    return this._length;
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: @CertainPerformance can you remove the hold from my question now